# How to find Event ID in source code at ticketmaster.co.uk? (Discovery API)

Tags: screen-scraping, ticketmaster

I'm trying to find an event id from the source code of an event page, say for example:

https://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/j-hus-champagne-experience-manchester-01-11-2023/event/1F005EE7BC123488

I know it's not the one in the URL (1F005EE7BC123488), so it has to be somewhere in the code.

Searching for `discoveryId` worked for U.S. events (.com), but it doesn't for U.K. Events.

It's insane how they don't even provide you with an ID, but have a whole API.